# how to calculate the difference between local peaks in a time-serie using R?

Tags: r, time-series

The data below shows 2 cycles or "loops". How can I get 1) the max (peak) and 2) last values of each cycle?

I need to calculate the difference between the peak of each cycle and the last value of the cycle immediately before [e.g. (peak of cycle 2) - (last value of cycle 1)]. I thought this was going to solve my problems: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22974/how-to-find-local-peaks-valleys-in-a-series-of-data
But the peaks that I am getting with the findPeak function, quantmod package (after trying many threshold values) do not make sense. I tried other functions (e.g. the one suggested by Whuber here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36309/how-do-i-find-peaks-in-a-dataset), but I have not been able to accurately calculate the peaks and, more challenging to me, the last datapoint of each cycle. I would really appreciate any help,

```
x <- 0:239
y <- c(12.32, 13.01, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 13.01, 13.01, 12.32, 
      12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 13.01, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 13.01, 
      12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 13.69, 13.69, 24.65, 39.71, 50.67, 76.69, 
      80.1, 98.6, 106.8, 109.6, 115, 116.4, 119.1, 123.2, 123.9, 131.5, 
      141.7, 143.8, 165, 180.8, 191.7, 212.9, 215.7, 231.4, 239, 241.7, 
      247.9, 250.6, 252, 255.4, 255.4, 258.1, 259.5, 259.5, 260.2, 
      261.6, 261.6, 263.6, 262.2, 263.6, 264.3, 264.3, 265, 265, 265, 
      265.7, 265, 264.3, 264.3, 265, 265, 265, 265, 264.3, 265, 264.3, 
      264.3, 263.6, 263.6, 263.6, 264.3, 263.6, 263.6, 262.2, 262.9, 
      262.2, 262.9, 261.6, 261.6, 260.9, 261.6, 260.9, 260.9, 260.2, 
      260.2, 259.5, 258.8, 258.8, 260.2, 258.1, 258.1, 258.1, 258.1, 
      258.1, 256.8, 256.8, 256.8, 256.1, 255.4, 255.4, 254.7, 254.7, 
      254, 254, 252.7, 253.3, 252.7, 252.7, 252, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 
      13.01, 13.01, 12.32, 13.01, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 
      11.64, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 12.32, 13.69, 
      13.01, 16.43, 18.49, 32.87, 58.2, 62.31, 90.4, 104.1, 110.2, 
      130.8, 135.6, 156.1, 170.5, 173.9, 186.2, 195.8, 202, 220.5, 
      223.2, 249.2, 274.6, 279.4, 302.6, 312.9, 319.1, 328, 328.7, 
      336.2, 338.9, 340.3, 343, 345.1, 346.5, 348.5, 349.2, 350.6, 
      351.2, 351.2, 352.6, 353.3, 353.3, 354, 354, 354.7, 354.7, 355.4, 
      354.7, 354, 354.7, 354.7, 354.7, 354, 354, 354, 353.3, 354, 353.3, 
      353.3, 353.3, 351.9, 352.6, 351.9, 351.2, 351.2, 351.2, 350.6, 
      350.6, 349.2, 349.2, 348.5, 348.5, 348.5, 348.5, 347.1, 347.8, 
      345.8, 346.5, 346.5, 345.8, 344.4, 345.1, 344.4, 344.4, 343, 
      341.7, 342.3, 341.7, 341.7, 340.3, 341, 341, 339.6, 338.9, 338.9, 
      338.9, 338.2, 337.6, 337.6, 337.6)
```

Comment: Would you please format that data? It's unusable in the present representation. Is it supposed to be a series of `(x,y)` pairs?

Comment: Also, is there a reason people need to see the entire data set (or at least that much?)

Comment: What language do you want to work in? If Python, I would suggest you use Pandas.

Comment: Can you identify the endpoints of each cycle? Or define what you mean by a cycle?

Comment: By cycle I mean each "loop" with a maximum (or peak). It should be pretty clear after plotting (x,y). For example, the first loop starts in (0, 12.32) and ends in (119, 252), and the second one starts in (120, 12.32) and ends in (239, 337.6). The peaks (y=265.7 and y=355.4) of the first and second "loops" are in x= 66 and x=186, respectively. My goal is to calculate the difference between the peak of each cycle and the last value of the cycle immediately before. In this case it would be the peak of the second cycle minus the last value of the first cycle i.e. 355.4 - 252 = 103.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is mainly about how you want to define a cycle rather than coding it in R. For example, if you want a new cycle to start whenever the difference between two consecutive points is greater than a threshold (eg 100) you can do so as follows

```
thres <- 100
cuts <- which(abs(diff(y)) > thres)
idx <- Map(seq, c(1, cuts + 1), c(cuts, length(x)))
cycles <- lapply(seq_along(idx), 
    function(i) data.frame(cycle = i, x = x[idx[[i]]], y = y[idx[[i]]]))
```

This will give you a list each element of which will contain the x and y values of a cycle. From that point on you can calculate statistics/summaries as required, eg to find the maximum of each cycle you can do

```
library(dplyr)
cycles.df <- bind_rows(cycles)
cycles.df %>% group_by(cycle) %>% slice(which.max(y))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: cycle
# 
#   cycle   x     y
# 1     1  66 265.7
# 2     2 186 355.4
```

or to find the last value in each cycle

```
cycles.df  %>% group_by(cycle) %>% slice(n())
# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: cycle
# 
#   cycle   x     y
# 1     1 119 252.0
# 2     2 239 337.6
```

Comment: Thanks konvas! That was really helpful

Comment: One following question. How can I get only one max value per cycle? I'm analyzing datasets in which I have small and large peaks. If I set a high threshold I get one max per cycle, but I miss the max values of the small peaks (diff between the min and max values is<threshold); if I set a low threshold I get the max values of all the peaks, but I get more than one max value for the large peaks (diff between some points in the large peaks is>threshold). I have tried many different threshold values but I'm always having any of these two problems. I would really appreciate any help,

Comment: It sounds like the question is about how you define a cycle.. you have to come up with some criteria that clearly define when a cycle ends and when another one starts. Just one criterion using a threshold for the difference between consecutive points may not be enough.